# Identify -- 4-pole Tippmatic illuminated rocker switch,15 A, 100 min cut-off

Tags: switches, identification

Can anyone identify this 4-pole, 100 minute cutoff switch?  It is the main power switch on a Moccamaster 741 (US variant/125 V).

I believe it is a Johnson Electric Tippmatic switch. I know it is a 15 A illuminated rocker switch. Please see the photo attached.

[image]

Comment: Four pole? That doesn't look like it has enough terminals to be four pole.

Comment: @Hearth: maybe he means "four pin" - I've seen others calling terminals "poles".

Comment: what do you mean by `100 minute cutoff`?

Comment: There appears to be some scorching on the left side. Yes the switch may be broken, but if you do not identify and correct what caused the scorching then you will just destroy another switch.

Comment: This is a switch for a coffee maker. I did mean 4 pin.  The switch cuts off after 100 minutes, to turn off the warming plate.  I believe water got into it and caused the short.

Comment: Related switch, not correct but perhaps a starting point. 
https://www.sparestore.com/en/coffee-maker-spares/43125-moccamaster-onoff-switch-ao-40-min